# How to properly retrieve package name of the app that inserted data to Google Fit?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I have a following code I am using to retrieve a list of user's activities from Google Fit:

```
public void getActivitiesData(Date from, Date till) {
    DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)
        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        .setTimeRange(from.getTime(), till.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build();

    Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(apiClient, readRequest).setResultCallback(new com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback<DataReadResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DataReadResult dataReadResult) {
            Status status = dataReadResult.getStatus();
            if (status.isSuccess()) {

                for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResult.getBuckets()) {
                    if (!bucket.getDataSets().isEmpty()) {
                        DataSet dataSet = bucket.getDataSets().get(0);
                        String sourceAppPackageName = getSourceAppPackageNameFromDataSet(dataSet);
                        for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                            for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                                String fieldName = field.getName();
                                if (fieldName != null && fieldName.equals("activity")) {
                                    String type = FitnessActivities.getValue(dp);
                                    Date from = new Date(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                                    Date till = new Date(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

                                    // store retrieved values to the data object, omitted
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private static String getSourceAppPackageNameFromDataSet(DataSet dataSet) {
    String result = null;

    if (dataSet.getDataSource() != null) {
        result = dataSet.getDataSource().getAppPackageName();
    }

    return result;
}
```

To insert activities into Google Fit, I've used the Google Fit app and Runkeeper (right now, these apps seem to be only ones that are integrated with Fit).

My code retrieves these activities as expected, however, for each activity, my `getSourceAppPackageNameFromDataSet()` method returns `"com.google.android.gms"` as a package name. As per [Data Attribution section in Google Fit documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-attribution), I would expect the method to return a package name of either Runkeeper or Google Fit, but this does not happen.

Am I doing something horribly wrong, or is this a bug in Google Fit?

Comment: I am busy adding upload support into my android app.  As I am not using the android api at all but using the rest apis I can not even set the package name so you need to be aware that you want always get one.  Sorry no idea about your specific issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataPoint.getOriginalDataSource().getAppPackageName()` will do the trick. It returns `com.withings.wiscale2` for my Withings scale, while `DataSet.getDataSource().getAppPackageName()`always returns `com.google.android.gms`.

There's a similar question right here: [DataSource.getAppPackageName() always returns "com.google.android.gms" in Google Fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34330471/datasource-getapppackagename-always-returns-com-google-android-gms-in-google)